# MySQL converting subquery to join

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to convert this subquery to join?

```
SELECT  `news`.`newsId`,
        (SELECT `comments`.`text` 
         FROM   `comments`   
         WHERE `comments`.`newsId` = `news`.`newsId` 
         order by `comments`.`date` desc 
         limit 1)   
FROM     `news` , `comments` 
where    `news`.`newsId` = `comments`.`newsId`   
GROUP BY `news`.`newsId` 
order by news.date desc;
```

Comment: What did you tried? Do you have data for us?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're trying to do is:

```
SELECT n.newsId FROM news n
INNER JOIN comments c ON c.newsId = n.newsId
ORDER BY c.date DESC, n.date
LIMIT 1
```

The GROUP BY is not necessary as you are not using any aggregation function. You can have unique entries with DISTINCT

Answer (score 0):

I assume `newsId` is unique.

```
SELECT  `news`.`newsId`,
        `comments`.`text`   
FROM     `news`
CROSS APPLY (SELECT `comments`.`text` 
             FROM   `comments`   
             WHERE `comments`.`newsId` = `news`.`newsId` 
             order by `comments`.`date` desc 
             limit 1) cm  
order by news.date desc;
```